# String Replacing In Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Suppose I have a variable with data in it:

```
string = "test('Text', '')"
```

How could I do something like this

```
string.replace("test('*', '')", "replacedtext")
```

So I could put a "*" in there and it would replace it if anything was there?

Comment: I wouldn't assign string either, it's a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to replace whatever text you may have within the single quotes within the string with "replacedtext". You don't need to use a wild card * for this.

`var newstring = string.replace(string.split("'")[1], "replacedtext");`

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply a `*` then:

```
string.replace('*', 'replacedText')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = yourString.replace(/\*/, "your string"); //result is now "your string"
```